# EF returns a Null object but the object isn't really null

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity named Game. This entity has 2 properties of type SubTeam. The subTeam has a Property of type Team (it's the parentteam for the subteams).

Now I create the subteams and the games and saves that to the database, without a relation to the parentteam (I don't know to what Team the subteams shall belong when I create them).

Later on I load the Game thru EF with this code..

```
        return contex.Games
            .Include(t => t.Serie)
            .Include(t => t.AwayTeam)
            .Include(t => t.HomeTeam)
            .SingleOrDefault(g => g.Identifier == gameIdentifier);
```

It works good and I get my Game and My SubTeams... But I know want to check if there is any ParentTeam in my subteams by checking if HomeTeam.ParentTeam != null. And here is something strange..

I can see that the HomeTeam.ParentTeam IS NULL and if I try to do this: HomeTeam.ParentTeam.Identifier I will get an exception. But when I do my if statment (HomeTeam.ParentTeam != null, then I will get True back, but that's not true HomeTeam.ParentTeam is NULL

I executed some lines in the immediate windows in VS2011. To get more information and I got this result:

```
homeTeam.ParentTeam
null
homeTeam.Users
null
(homeTeam.ParentTeam == null ? "True" : "False")
"False"
(homeTeam.Users == null ? "True" : "False")
"True"
```

How does it come that my hometeam.ParentTeam says it's NULL and if I try to use it I will get an exception, but the IF-Statements will tell my that the homeTeam.ParentTeam isn't NULL.

What is EF doing here? And how do I check if an object in EF is NULL when it's really is NULL.

I don't use virtual in my entities so it's not a proxy problem.

Comment: What does it say if you ask the immediate window to print `homeTeam.ParentTeam`?

Comment: It says NULL the value above shows what I print in the Immediate window and the response so if I only print "homeTeam.ParentTeam" the response is null. But if I print (homeTeam.ParentTeam == null ? "True" : "False") then the response is "False"...